# Exercises to do while cycling?

Tags: exercise

Sometimes when I am cycling I will try to do some stretching to alleviate some backpain. Usually I arch my back, or push into the pedal and straighten my leg and stretch.

Does anyone do something similar? If so, can you share the stretches, exercises you do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to warm up / stretch and cool down?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/how-to-warm-up-stretch-and-cool-down)

Comment: For actual pain (not only being tired), there's not best remedy than walking, pushing the bike. Just one minute, and you go back on the bike quite refreshed. (perhaps not enough to catch up with your gone friends... ;oP )

Comment: I think just stretch what it feels good to stretch, and try to change positions regularly.  And as Helton suggests, taking a break every now and again is good too.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't experience pain on a well-fit bike. If you are finding that you have a lot of pain while cycling, you probably have one of two problems:

1. Your bike doesn't fit right. Back pain probably indicates that the distance to your handlebars is too long.
2. You didn't stretch well enough before hand or have aggravated an existing injury. You should probably get off the bike and relax a bit. Maybe talk to a doctor.

Comment: The back pain doesn't come from cycling, it's more from just stiff back and I try to stretch while cycling.

Saying that, I am trying to find out if my bars are the right distance/saddle is right height.

Comment: I think you're unrealistic to claim that you shouldn't experience pain while cycling.  Six hours into a ride every bone in my body is hurting.